# How to capture words inside a bracket using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to find the following methods

```
POST
GET
DELETE
```

from:

```
[POST]
[GET]
[DELETE]
```

My current regex is:

```
[A-Z\w+]
```

But it does not return what I need. What am I doing wrong?

Also, please note that for each line, only one value is inside the brackets, it is either POST, GET, or DELETE. Lastly, these methods are inside a log file which also has other characters inside "[]" (a url or a rails helper method). I only need the to get POST, GET, or DELETE.

Comment: Have you tried using tools like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)?

Comment: something like `\[([^\]]+)\]`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use capturing groups `()` to extract the value between the escaped `\[` and `\]`,
and target everything `[]` that is not `^` a closing `\]` one or more times `+`.

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/pYkYAp/1

If you want to focus **on the exact words** `POST GET` etc than use options `|`:

```
\[(POST|DELETE|GET)\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/pYkYAp/2/

If you want to be less picky and **go for uppercase *terms*** only than:

```
\[([A-Z]+)\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/pYkYAp/3/

If you **don't need captures and full matches** than you could use Positive lookbehind `(?<=…)` and positive lookahead `(?=…)`:

```
(?<=\[)[A-Z]+(?=\])
```

https://regex101.com/r/pYkYAp/4/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should do it `\[([^]]+)\]` to capture everything within brackets. `\[([POST|GET|PUT|DELETE]]+)\]` to capture specific predefined words.

Comment: almost, but the thing is I'm trying to parse a log file, and there are other parts of it that also has "[ ]" with other characters inside

Comment: \[([POST|GET|DELETE|WHATEVER]]+)\] should be what you're looking for.